# Error on activating account on docker -alphanet

Tags: docker, alphanet, account

I am having an error on running this command:

```
./alphanet.sh client activate account faucetWallet with /home/tezos/tz1cb1qWTU7WTXKhLJ8HgoNoJcGeLp3mXK6g.json --force
```

and I get:

```
Warning:

                 This is NOT the Tezos Mainnet.

     The node you are connecting to claims to be running on the
               Tezos Alphanet DEVELOPMENT NETWORK.
          Do NOT use your fundraiser keys on this network.
          Alphanet is a testing network, with free tokens.

Node is bootstrapped, ready for injecting operations.
Operation successfully injected in the node.
Operation hash is 'oooBJhi5pTbdBnV6dDEEgTepaPRgATuefgoTPo38GUkCZvLgRwM'
Waiting for the operation to be included...
Fatal error:
  The operation oooBJhi5pTbdBnV6dDEEgTepaPRgATuefgoTPo38GUkCZvLgRwM is outdated and may never be included in the chain.
  We recommand to use an external block explorer.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I notice my script has a `-d basedir` (your tezos client dir), does it help adding that? `tezos-client -A $NODE_HOST -d $basedir --wait none activate account "$account" with $faucet --force`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, though that didn't make any difference for me

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, in my case it says that the command is not recognized, if a run man, the activate command does not exists. nicosampler@nfd-ubuntu:~$ ./alphanet.sh client activate account test with "container:tz1MzsE4cocSfss5cnav8UWzxnbrrZH32Rij.json" Error: Unrecognized command. Try using the man command to get more information.

Answer (score 1):

I think you node hadn't sync with the alphanet full block yet.

after start your docker or if you build from source that execute this bellow command

```
./tezos-node run --rpc-addr 127.0.0.1:8732 --connections 10
```

You need to wait until the block fully sync, to verify the block execute bellow command:

```
./tezos-client bootstrapped
```

If you see the timestamp and validation then it's should be able to go now.